# QuickSort on a doubly linked list not working as it should

Tags: c, linked-list, quicksort

I used an algorithm that I've used in the past for arrays. This always picks the first element as the pivot. Here's the code:

```
void quickSort(int a[],int l,int r,int *count)
{
    if(l<r-1)
    {
        *count=*count+r-l-1;
        int q=partition(a,l,r); //finding the pivot position in sorted array
        quickSort(a,l,q-1,count);     //recursive calling before pivot sub array
        quickSort(a,q+1,r,count);     //recursive calling after pivot sub array
    }
}

//partition function definition
int partition(int a[],int l,int r)
{
    int j,temp,i=l+1;

    for(j=l+1;j<r;j++)
    {
        //swap values if a[j]<=a[r](i.e. pivot)
        if(a[j]<=a[l])
        {
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
            i++;
        }
    }
    //place pivot at its position by swapping
    temp=a[i-1];
    a[i-1]=a[l];
    a[l]=temp;
    return i;
}
```

Now here is when I try to implement this to a doubly linked list. "head" represents the head to the linked list

```
void recQuick(void* head, node* s, node* e, int (*comparator)(void*,void*)) {    
    //s = (node*) head;


    if ( e != NULL && s != e && s != e->next ) { //we want to cycle through the linked list

        node* pivot = (node*) realQuickSorter(head,s,e,(comparator)); 


        recQuick(head,s,pivot->prev, (comparator));

        recQuick(head,pivot->next,e, (comparator));
    }

    //return 1;

}

node* realQuickSorter ( void* head, node* s, node* e, int (*comparator)(void*,void*)) { 

    char* piv = s->str; //will always be the first element

    node* leader = s->next;

    //node* ii = s->next;

    node* follower = leader;


    for ( follower = leader; follower != e ; follower = follower->next ) {

        if ( ((comparator)(follower->str,s->str)) == 1 ) { //pivot is bigger, we need to swap

            swap(&(follower->str),&(leader->str));

            leader = (leader == NULL) ? s : leader->next;
            //leader = leader->next;
        }

    }

    swap(&(s->str),&(leader->prev->str));

    return leader->prev;
}
```

Functions like swap, bringMeEnd are correct

The linked list version only seems to swap the first two when out of order, leaving the rest the same

Comment: Not answering your question, but quicksort is best to be used on arrays. If you have a linked list then a merge sort might be easier and better.

Comment: @ybungalobill This isn't a quicksort at all.

Comment: @EOF would you mind elaborating

Comment: In a quicksort, you would compare the currently indexed element with the pivot. You're not using the pivot at all. Also, I'd recommend Hoare partitioning, it's less braindamaged.

Comment: the pivot in myprogram is always the first element of the linked list, am i not implenting that right? @EOF

Comment: Your comparison: `if ( ((comparator)(follower->str,s->str)) == 1 )`. *Which* of these is supposed to be the pivot `char* piv = s->str;`?

Comment: Please add enough code to the question so that the code can be compiled and tested.

Comment: regarding: `if(a[j]<=a[l])
        {
            temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[i];
            a[i]=temp;
            i++;
        }`  Why perform the swap if the two entries are the same?  Suggest replacing: `if(a[j]<=a[l])` with `if(a[j] < a[l])`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding, use meaningful variable names.

Comment: what is the definition of the 'node'?

Comment: OT:: regarding: `node* pivot = (node*) realQuickSorter(head,s,e,(comparator));`  The actual function: `realQuickSorter()` already has a return type of `node*` so no cast is needed.   Did you remember to use prototypes for each of the functions?

Comment: in functions: `realQuick()` and `realQuickSorter()`  Why the parameter `head` when it is never used?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: regarding: `swap(&(follower->str),&(leader->str));`  Cannot swap the strings, Suggest only swapping the pointers to the strings.

Comment: @rcgldr,  NEVER make assumptions about what the OP designed,  Rather, let the OP inform you/us

Comment: @rcgldr, I read LOTS of code on stackoverflow where the OP stated the code compiled and runs.  Then I copy paste the OPs code into a editor.compiler, like `geany`  and the resulting list of warnings (and errors) goes on and on.  So, I NEVER make the assumption that the code compiles.  Does this mean the OP lied?  OR does it mean the OP did not successfully copy the code into the question?

Answer (score 1):

You try to implement quicksort for linked lists based on an already existing implementation for arrays. You do so by swapping the nodes' values. In my opinion, that's not ideal. Linked lists are not arrays. You should swap the nodes instead.

(There's probably a reason your data exists as linked list. If the nodes' payload is large, swapping the data is ineffecient. If you have outside pointers to the nodes, swapping will invalidate them.)

How does quicksort work?

- Pick a pivot and remove it from the list.
- Partition the remaining list into

  1. elements that are less than the pivot (*le*),
  2. elements that are equal to the pivot and
  3. elements that are greater than the pivot (*gt*) by some metric.
- Run quicksort on the partitions so that you list now looks like this:
  sorted *le* partition   |   pivot   |   sorted *gt* partition

In the array implementation, you achieve that by swapping the elements around and by moving the pivot. That's a good strategy, because that way you need extra space.

In a linked list, you can create the partitions by extracting the current list into two partition lists. Call quicksort on those and then stitch them together again with the pivot in the middle.

If you have lists with many elements that have the same value, i.e. that compare equal, you can make the single-node pivot a third list, *eq*.

Here's some code that does that. The functions

- `pop`, which pops the first node off a list;
- `append` which appends a node at the end of a list and
- `join`, which appends the second list to the first

are not shown, but the algorithm itself should be clear. It is pretty straightforward. Each node has a `next` and ´prev`pointer as well as some`data`; a list has`head`and`tail` pointers.

Anyway, here goes:

```
void quicksort(List *list)
{
    if (list->head != list->tail) {
        List eq = {NULL, NULL};
        List lt = {NULL, NULL};
        List gt = {NULL, NULL};

        append(&eq, pop(list));

        while (list->head) {
            Node *node = pop(list);

            int cmp = compare(node->data, eq.head->data);

            if (cmp < 0) {
                append(&lt, node);
            } else if (cmp > 0) {
                append(&gt, node);
            } else {
                append(&eq, node);
            }
        }

        quicksort(&lt);
        quicksort(&gt);

        join(list, &lt);
        join(list, &eq);
        join(list, &gt);
    }
}
```

This sorting agoritm is stable: Elements with the same value have the same order in the sorted and in the original list. A complete example program that includes the functions `pop`, `join` and `extract`is [here on ideone](https://ideone.com/GtR9Hw).

Comment: Why not just make 3 lists, < pivot | == pivot | > pivot, then only recurse on the 2 lists != pivot?

Comment: I suggest that in the blurb before the code. Should be an easy improvment. ´:)`

Comment: If `str` is a pointer to a string, then each node's "value" is a pointer to string, and the overhead of swapping pointers is less that relinking nodes to swap them. Creating lists as you have suggested may be faster.

Comment: What are you trying to get at, @rcgldr? I've said "if the payload is large" and you provide a case where it isn't. The point of my answer is that quicksort for a linked list should probably not be implemented like a quicksort on an array. I am aware that I have not answered the OP's question ("What's wrong with my qs?"), but I think that that question is wrong-headed.

Comment: (I'm also aware that my answer isn't ideal: I have used a singly linked list instead of a doubly linked list, where the code for extracting and inserting nodes is different and where the list itself already holds the tail.)

Comment: Looking at the swap function call in the OP, it node.str is probably a pointer to a string, and that a pair of pointers to strings are being swapped. Otherwise the parameters, (&...->str, &...->str) doesn't make sense, since the compare uses parameters (...->str, ...->str) without the dereferencing `&`s.

Comment: Frankly, I haven't looked too closely at OP's code except to see that it tries to implement an array sort on a linked list. But we are talking at cross purposes here: You want to answer OP's question and I think that the question does not make a lot of sense to begin with. I've said so and I stand by it. It's likely that the question is homework. If so, the code should be about swapping nodes, because that's the thing to learn here.

Comment: If the code tries to solve a real probem, then use a dynamic array and run `qsort` on it. Or, if the list is small,  use a linked list and keep the nodes sorted while inserting. Or use a balanced binary tree. Anyway, it was a nice little coding exercise for a Saturday evening that carried over to Sunday, because I now rewrote it for doubly-linked lists. That's as much fun I'll ever get out of this question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *e* is a pointer to the last node in a sub-list, the for loop in realQuickSorter() stops before comparing the last node with the pivot. There may be other issues.

It would help if compare and swap functions were included, as well as the code that generates the test list and calls recQuick().

---

Here is example code based on the original question. The fixes are noted in comments. I changed variable names to match some old code I had. The names `follower` and `leader` were backwards from the way they are used. In my example code, I switched to using `pi` and `pj`, as pointer to node equivalents to indexes `i` and `j` as used for arrays. I reversed the sense of the compare function to be the same as strcmp (assuming the goal is to sort from lowest to highest string value).

recQuick was missing a check for lo (`s`) == NULL, which can happen if the pivot ends up in the first node, where pivot->prev == NULL. realQuickSorter needed two fixes: include the last node (hi or `e`) when comparing versus pivot. If the pivot ends up in the last node, then pi (`leader`) may end up as NULL (if hi->next == NULL), so a check is made and pi is set to hi in this case, else it's set to pi->prev.

```
typedef struct node_{
    struct node_ * next;
    struct node_ * prev;
    char * str;
}node;

void recQuick(node* lo, node* hi, int (*comparator)(void*,void*))
{
    node* pv;
    if(lo == NULL || hi == NULL || lo == hi || lo == hi->next) /* fix */
        return;
    pv = (node*) realQuickSorter(lo,hi,(comparator));
    recQuick(lo, pv->prev, (comparator));
    recQuick(pv->next, hi, (comparator));
}

node* realQuickSorter(node* lo, node* hi, int (*comparator)(void*, void*))
{ 
    node* pi = lo->next;
    node* pj;
    for(pj = pi; pj != hi->next ; pj = pj->next ){  /* fix */
        if(((comparator)(pj->str, lo->str)) <= 0 ){ /* changed comparator */
            swap(&(pj->str),&(pi->str));
            pi = pi->next;                          /* fix */
        }
    }
    if(pi == hi->next)                              /* fix (hi->next could be NULL) */
        pi = hi;                                    /* fix */
    else                                            /* fix */
        pi = pi->prev;                              /* fix */
    swap(&(lo->str),&(pi->str));                    /* fix */
    return pi;                                      /* fix */
}
```

---

This is an inefficient way to sort a linked list. M Oehm's answer should be a bit better, but a bottom up merge sort for linked list would be faster:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

On a large list with scattered nodes, despite what algorithm is used, every node access could involve a cache miss. Assuming enough memory, it would be faster to copy the list data into an array, sort the array, and create a new linked list.