# Quick sort on Linked list, how to make this code use first elment as pivot rather than last

Tags: c, linked-list, quicksort

WHat chages would I have to implement for this code to work using the first element as a pivot rather than the last?

Any approach I've taken hasn't worked, any help would be appreciated, thanks!!!!!!

```
struct Node* partition(struct Node *l, struct Node *h) 
{ 
    // set pivot as h element 
    int x = h->data; 

    // similar to i = l-1 for array implementation 
    struct Node *i = l->prev; 

    // Similar to "for (int j = l; j <= h- 1; j++)" 
    for (struct Node *j = l; j != h; j = j->next) 
    { 
        if (j->data <= x) 
        { 
            // Similar to i++ for array 
            i = (i == NULL) ? l : i->next; 

            swap(&(i->data), &(j->data)); 
        } 
    } 
    i = (i == NULL) ? l : i->next; // Similar to i++ 
    swap(&(i->data), &(h->data)); 
    return i; 
} 

/* A recursive implementation of quicksort for linked list */
void _quickSort(struct Node* l, struct Node *h) 
{ 
    if (h != NULL && l != h && l != h->next) 
    { 
        struct Node *p = partition(l, h); 
        _quickSort(l, p->prev); 
        _quickSort(p->next, h); 
    } 
} 

// The main function to sort a linked list. 
// It mainly calls _quickSort() 
void quickSort(struct Node *head) 
{ 
    // Find last node 
    struct Node *h = lastNode(head); 

    // Call the recursive QuickSort 
    _quickSort(head, h); 
}
```

Any approach I've taken hasn't worked, any help would be appreciated, thanks!!!!!!

Comment: This is very similar to your [prior question, now answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60466837/60471013#60471013) which I have answered with example code (using first node as the pivot).

Answer (score 0):

```
// set pivot as h element 
int x = h->data;
```

Set pivot as the low element, that is the first element, here:

```
int x = l->data;
```